# Redirect subfolder to index

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following URLs

http://example.org/oldbutgold/1.html

http://example.org/oldbutgold/2.html

### ---

And a lot more like that, I would like to redirect those links to:

http://example.org/goldies/

How could I do it?

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldbutgold(.*)$ http://example.org/goldies/
```